# Nutch login to website for crawling

Tags: web-crawler, jsoup, nutch

I need to crawl post of a website `https://hl.com` using nutch but this websites ask for login on certain pages. Like for profile and certain posts. So i need to first authenticate, i tried with below code but its not working am getting a blank html.

```
String url="https://hl.com/user/Joanne74";
Connection.Response res =
Jsoup.connect("https://hl.com/login")
.data("email", "email", "password",
"mypassword").method(Method.POST).timeout(0).execute();

Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = connection.cookies(cookies).timeout(0).get();
```

Comment: You should give it a try to the `protocol-selenium` plugin (https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/protocol-selenium) This will allow you to fetch content that is loaded by javascript. Combining this with the authentication could be tricky, but you could take a look at the `protocol-httpclient` to see how it is handled, right now we offer basic support for POST authentication (like a normal form, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

This page is tricky. It relies heavily on javascript to load dynamic content with ajax.

1. Login form posts username and password to `https://healthunlocked.com/api/session` (instead of `https://healthunlocked.com/login`). You can preview it using your browser's debugger.
2. Use `.ignoreContentType(true)` to avoid `Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type.` because it sends JSON as a response.
3. Parsing `https://healthunlocked.com/user/Joanne74` is useless as it loads only some javascript, but you can use debugger to observe additional requests for content:
   `https://healthunlocked.com/api/posts?userId=909195`  or 
   `https://healthunlocked.com/api/activity?filter=user-activity-public&pageNumber=1&id=909195` or 
   `https://healthunlocked.com/api/profile?username=Joanne74&showPrivateFields=false`
   to get all the info you need, but then again - it's JSON, so you're going to need additional library other than jsoup to parse it further.